# Hiding fields with Django crispy forms

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have the following in my forms.py :

```
class DocumentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Documents  # Your User model
        fields = ['EMAIL', 'OWNERFULLNAME', 'OWNERSTREET', 'OWNERCITY', 'OWNERSTATE', 'OWNERZIP', 'DATE']
        labels = {

            'EMAIL': 'Owner Email',
            'OWNERFULLNAME': 'Owner Address',
            'OWNERSTREET': 'Owner Street',
            'OWNERCITY': 'Owner City ',
            'OWNERSTATE': 'Owner State',
            'OWNERZIP': 'Owner Zip',

            'DATE': I WANT THIS AS A HIDDEN FIELD',

            # 'captcha': "Enter captcha"

        }

    helper = FormHelper()

    helper.form_method = 'POST'
    helper.form_action = "/contact/"
    helper.form_id = 'form'  # SET THIS OR BOOTSTRAP JS AND VAL.JS WILL NOT WORK
    helper.add_input(Submit('Submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary'))
```

I want to Hide the date field, In the docs (https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html) , this can be handled using the

```
Field('field_name', type="hidden")
```

Can this be done using the format above using the formhelper class (https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_helpers.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add:

```
helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('DATE', type="hidden"))
```

and it worked.